# How to render react navigation drawer config based on API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to setup react navigation and the idea is to have a structure like this:

```
LoadingStack (Switch Navigator)  
    Loading: LoadingScreen (Screen)  
    Main: BottomTabBar (Bottom Tab Navigator)  
             Home: DrawerNav (Drawer Navigator  
                     [Multiple categories within drawer all with the same screen] 
             Settings: SettingScreen (Screen)
             More: MoreScreen (Screen)
```

The different categories I will use to build the drawerNavigator config will come from an API and my plan is to fetch from the API in the LoadingScreen within the top switch navigator.

I am struggling to figure out how to get this data to the correct place to build the drawer navigator though.  I initially tried to have the 'Home' route within the BottomTabBar be a screen component and then I could pass the API results into that screen, build the drawer config and then manually return the drawerNavigator, which is what this answer on stack overflow is referring to I think: [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469918/react-navigation-drawer-dynamically-routes-and-navigation-items) however I get an invarient error that there is no navigation prop available.

So I guess my question is how can I build the drawer navigator based on data I will fetch in the switch navigators loading screen?

Comment: where you store your config data that you fetch in the SwitchNavigator ... redux store  or what ?

Comment: I am not storing it anywhere, and I don't need to store it.  All I need to do it pass it into a spot where I can generate the drawerNavigator

Comment: Alright ... check out my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const YourDrawer = ({ field1, field2 }) => {
  const RouteConfigs = {
    // ...
  };

  const DrawerNavigatorConfig = {
    // ...
  };
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig);

  return <YourDrawer />;
};

const YourTabNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  const field1Value = navigation.getParam('field1');
  const field2Value = navigation.getParam('field1');

  const RouteConfigs = {
    Home: (props) => <YourDrawer { ...props } field1={field1Value} field2={field2Value} />,
    // Rest of routes...
  };
  const YouTab = createTabNavigator(RouteConfigs);

  return <YourTab />;
};

export default createAppContainer(YourTabNavigator);

class Loading extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if (dataFetched) {
      this.props.navigationnavigate('Main', {
        field1: 'someVal',
        field2: 'someVal',
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is almost exactly what I have been trying.  And then I would put the 'YourDrawer' component as the screen for the drawer navigator?

Because if I do that then I get an error that I lose the navigation and I shouldn't put a navigator inside of a screen...

Comment: Unless I wrap the whole thing inside another createAppContainer() but then I would have 2 appContainers....

Comment: Check out the edit ... for this to work, you need to downgrade to `react-navigation` version 2 ... to get rid of this `createAppContainer` thing

Comment: That seems kind of hacky, and basically it is just implicitly creating another appContainer...Thank you for the help though I will keep working on it

Comment: yes it did create appContainer internally ... btw if your using redux or any sort of global state management ... the solution would be more straightforward .. and good luck anyway

Comment: If I implemented redux could I do it without having to downgrade to version 2?

Comment: I guess it should work ... cause you're gonna mapStateToProps directly to your DrawerComponent .. .and then wrap your root Navigator (which is the TabNavigator) with createAppContainer...

Side Node: I use react navigation version 2 in all of my projects and it works perfectly.

Comment: and you know what the solution I'm suggesting ... should also work with react-navigation v3 ..